# R: Passing list of assignment statements to be executed and assignment variables stored

Tags: r

Given some sample data for reference:

```
sn,fail_type,dt
V12001,broken ego,2018-12-07 15:58:33
V12002,batt overheat,2018-10-11 22:33:51
V12003,batt overheat,2018-10-26 15:02:51
V12004,broken ego,2018-09-28 15:44:46
V12005,cognitive meltdown,2018-12-31 02:30:04
V12006,won't turn on,2018-12-14 02:05:41
V12007,won't turn on,2018-12-02 21:14:29
V12008,bad system board,2018-11-02 16:30:57
V12009,petulant child operator,2018-09-06 14:53:25
V12010,leaky pump,2018-11-05 14:41:48
V12011,leaky pump,2018-11-04 18:05:11
V12012,petulant child operator,2018-11-23 16:34:54
V12013,cognitive meltdown,2018-09-11 18:07:50
V12014,cognitive meltdown,2018-10-26 22:55:32
V12015,leaky pump,2018-09-19 14:05:29
V12016,no alarm,2018-11-05 23:44:08
V12017,petulant child operator,2018-12-18 14:02:34
V12018,leaky pump,2018-10-08 04:13:41
V12019,bad system board,2018-09-03 02:28:16
V12020,leaky pump,2018-11-10 07:10:50
```

I create a data.table called ts_vars from the above.

I then want to isolate the unique list of fail_types and get time-series event data based for each unique fail_type.

```
# get unique list
ft_list <- unique(ts_vars$fail_type)

# clean up unnecessary punctuation
ft_list <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", ft_list)
```

The next thing I wish to do is create a list of expressions that can be executed row-by-row, and the assignments stored in memory as I will use them for plotting (yep, alot of them). I know, I know, I'm using a `for` loop, and apply/plyr'ish methods are better, but putting this out there as a quick/dirty MWE.

```
cmdvec <- function() {
  for (i in (1:length(ft_list))) {
    # name a variable, ts_var, with a numeric suffix
    nam <- paste("ts_var",i, sep="")

    # stitch together an assignment statement which will store a vector of 
      events by fail_type, allowing a separate plot for each

    sub <- paste("subset(ts_vars,ts_vars$fail_type==",ft_list[i], sep="'", ")")
    ts_cmd[i] <- paste(nam,sub,sep=" <- ")
    # parse each statement to be evaluated and store in a vector for execution
    ts_cmd2 <- as.vector(eval(parse(text = ts_cmd[i]), envir = new.env()))
    ts_cmd2
    # print(ts_cmd2)
  }
}

cmdvec()
```

As-is, nothing really happens. I see no results from execution nor new stored vectors (`ts_var1 through ts_var187`). If I substitute `ts_cmd` for `print(ts_cmd)`, the statements are evaluated and I get results in the console, but none of the assignments are stored.

I've tried eval'ing the last statement, calling it (but I can't fathom what parameters I would add), converting the character list to expressions - but I'm missing some critical points here, and I think I've hit all docs in base R on this and picked some ideas from other tangential SO questions. I'm stumped now. In sum, I just can't seem to pass a simple list of statements as bona-fide commands to be processed one-by-one AND have the assignment variable be stored for downstream use (plots, other independent analyses, etc).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't recreate a bunch of variables with values embedded in their name. That's very difficult to work with in R. Instead split your data inot a list. It seems like you just need some variant of `split(ts_vars, ts_vars$fail_type)`. It's pretty much never a good idea to build commands as strings and eval/parse them.

Comment: If  I understood you correctly, I  can see the wisdom in not bludgeoning the environment with 187 new variables (numeric suffixes for variables are simply a quick way to differentiate one output from another). However there's a real need in this case (quite alot of output) and for my hardware, this is fairly trivial. What it boils down to is that I simply need to get event data by datetime for each unique fail_type and then be able to do other things with each output dataset independently (plots, further analysis, etc).

Comment: Then that's exactly what a list will do. You can map any function over the list. Just start with the `split()`